# count the same hash values in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

Suppose I have the following hash table in ruby,

```
  H = {"I"=>3, "Sam"=>2, "am"=>2, "do"=>1, "not"=>1, "eat"=> 1}
```

I want to construct the following hash table N  from H

```
  N = {"1" => 3, "2"=>2, "3"=>1}
```

where 3 in value signifies number of hash entires with value "1" in H (e.g. `"do"=>1, "not"=>1, "eat"=> 1`, therefore `"1" => 3`)

Is there any easy way in ruby to construct the  N hash table from H??

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4):

```
 Hash[H.values.group_by{|i| i}.map {|k,v| [k, v.count]}]
```

Update: to get strings as keys and sorted by key:

```
Hash[h.values.group_by{|i| i}.map {|k,v| [k.to_s, v.count]}.sort]
```

Comment: Could also use `group_by(&:last)` and `to_h` instead of `Hash#[]` for Ruby 2: `H.group_by(&:last).map {|k,v| [k, v.size]}.to_h`

Comment: O/p `{3=>1, 2=>2, 1=>3}` is not same as expected like `{"1" => 3, "2"=>2, "3"=>1}`

Comment: @Lee is right: extracting the values is unnecessary and wasteful. Incidentally, we finally got [Object#itself](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-itself) in v2.2 (`1.itself => 1` `"cat".itself => "cat" `), so we can now write, `a.group_by(&:itself)` instead of `a.group_by { |e| e }`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
N = {}
H.values.each { |t| N["#{t}"] = (N["#{t}"] || 0) + 1}
```

Comment: There's no need to extract a temporary array containing the values, just `H.each { |_,t| ...`.

Comment: yaah, you are right @CarySwoveland. Its also a better solution.

Comment: Come on, This does not provide an answer to the question ? I mean How ?

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution:

```
H.values.sort.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|ac,e| ac[e.to_s]+=1;ac}
# {"1"=>3, "2"=>2, "3"=>1}
```

Comment: Using `inject` with `<op>; <value>` is often a sign inject is being used where `each_with_object` would be better: `H.values.sort.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|e,ac| ac[e]+=1 }`

Comment: Good point, although won't use it in the answer as it wouldn't be mine ;)

Comment: David, in my opinion, if an improvement is suggested, you should edit and include it, providing an acknowledgement in the answer or a comment. It's the answer--not your contribution to it--that's important (for readers, anyway :-)). I suggest you not extract the values (a wasteful step) and not sort them (not asked for), so it's just `H.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(_,v),h| ...Lastly, you might mention that `Hash.new(0)` is sometimes called a "counting hash".